# Finding Labour Supply in Cobb Douglas type Utility Function

Tags: macroeconomics, self-study

Once again self-study question:

Given a household's utility function be:

$$U = C^\alpha (1-L)^\beta$$

where, $L$ is labor supplied. Total labor time is normalized to $1$. $C$ is read household consumption, which is taken to be equal to its wage income, i.e., real wage into labor.

1. Find FOC for utility maximization and derive household's labor supply ($L$) for a given real wage, $w$. Does $L$ depend on $w$? Give explanation.

My attempt: I simply substituted $C = wL$ in the utility function and differentiated (after taking log - to make it simple) w.r.t $L$ to obtain the following:

$$L^* = \alpha / (\alpha + \beta)$$

I am unable to properly explain why is this independent of $w$. On the contrary it feels counter intuitive because real wage should be equal to MRS which is doesn't seem to be constant.

2. Assuming for the economy production function is $Y= AL^\theta$. And aggregate demand of economy is given by $C+I$ where $I$ is exogenously given investment level. Find equilibrium output for this economy for some given $I$. What role does $\theta$ play? Provide and intuitive answer.

My attempt: shouldn't answer simply be $A(L^*)^\theta$?

---

EDIT: Revisiting this question, I made some progress. For part (1), as suggested in comments, I can use the fact that elasticity of substitution for this utility function is $1$. Therefore, the ratio of consumption to leisure increases by same amount as $w$. Since consumption is directly proportional to $w$, leisure consumption remains same.

For part (2), introducing another variable $n$: number of households employed at equilibrium. So:

$$w = Y_L|_{L = nL^*} =  \theta A (nL^*)^{\theta - 1}$$
Now I think a confusion arose because of same choice of variable symbols in the question, denoting $c$ by aggregate consumption (somewhat opposite of convention though):

$$c = nwL^* = \theta A (nL^*)^\theta$$

$$Y = A(nL^*)^\theta$$

If the above is correct, $\theta$ acts as the $1-s$, where $s$ is aggregate saving rate.

Since $I$ is exogenous, $n$ will adjust to bring equilibrium. I still don't know what 'intuitive' explanation can be given here.

Comment: Have you ever encountered Cobb Douglas type utility functions before, do you know if they have any sort of special property?

Comment: @Giskard: Constant elasticity of substitution?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I think I found the answer on wiki: "...*when the elasticity of substitution is exactly one (as in the Cobb–Douglas case), expenditure on $c_{2}$ relative to $c_{1}$ is independent of the relative prices*". How about second part of the question? Is my answer correct?

Comment: I don't think it is independent of w. You could use a monotonic transformation instead f(u) = ln(u), which makes your calculation easier.